# Arithmetic progression on finding first term and common difference

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to do with the question ask to find out the values of a= first term and d=common difference if the sum of the first four term is equal to three times the fourth term and the eighteenth term is 3? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Can you explain a little on what you think of the problem or add some background to what you already know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1. The sum of the first four terms is $a+(a+d)+(a+2d)+(a+3d)=4a+6d$.
2. The fourth term is $a+3d$.
3. The eighteenth term is $a+17d$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}+a_{4}=3\\a_{18}=3\\a_{n}=a_{1}+(n-1)d\\so\\a_{1}+(a_{1}+d)+(a_{1}+2d)+(a_{1}+3d)=3\\a_{1+17d=3}=3\\so\\4a_{1}+6d=3\\a_{1}+17d=3\\solve- the- system-of-equation$$

Comment: Your fifth line is incorrect, the sum of the first four terms does not equal $3$.